# sending a form to a service

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring form which is called `AddNewItemForm` and contains the validation annotations.

This form is the parameter of my Spring `RestController` `addNewItem()` method and it will be validated, the results being stored in `BindingResults`.

From my controller I need to call the service. Here is my question. Is it ok to have a method inside my service with this signature

```
public Item add(AddNewItemForm form)
```

or is it better to have it like

```
public Item add(Item item)
```

I am thinking that the form is only needed for the controller validation but the service doesn't need to know about it. It just needs to know how to operate with entities.

I suppose that I should construct my `Item` in the controller, with all the data I have and then pass this item to the service `add(item)` method.

Am I right?

Comment: There could be cases where validation is possible on Service layer. E.g. it's not possible to create a new item if an item with the name already exists or e.g. item owner user is blocked

Comment: I was referring strictly to passing a form, used in controller for validation, to a service. I validate in both places, controller and service. In controller I validate the form inputs and in service I validate almost the same inputs against other kind of logic like the one you referred to.

Comment: I would agree to your last suggestion. Validating the form-input in the controller -> parsing it to a service-object and send it to the Service, which validates the Item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it in terms of dependencies: your web layer always needs to know about your service module and by passing the AddNewItemForm (which I assume exists in your web module/package) back to your service you now have a circular dependency.

Dependencies should only flow downwards:

Repository > Service > Web

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view the service should not know about your command object (AddNewItemForm) since they are totally independent.

I agree with your last suggestion, you have to construct your model object before calling your service. Basically in your controller or with the help of an utility class.